# Specflow scenario outline with then table

Tags: specflow

I have a scenario outline with an example table with multiple rows having unique test parameters that are being used for given statement and **then** statement table for verification. Basically when the scenario gets run with the first row of examples table, I want to use the first row of **then** table to verify the result and so on.

Is it possible to do this? If not should I go with another scenario design?

```
Feature: MyFuture  

@Do something  
Scenario Outline: Verify bla bla    
    Given run I ... with <jj>,<kk>,<ll>  
    Then verify the following  
    | aa  |  bb | cc |  
    | d   |  e  | f  |  
    | g   |  h  | i  | 

Examples:  
    | jj | kk | ll |  
    | m  | n  | o  |  
    | p  | q  | r  |
```

Comment: Technically instead of using a THEN table I can add it to Examples table but in that case I have to create multiple then statements (I have 8 then statements) and if one of them gets failed, the remaining then statements do not get asserted. That's why I want to use one single then table to insert all my assertions using Assert.Multiple.. so I can check if the remaining tests are failed or passed instead of skipping.

Answer (score 1):

Add your assertions to the examples table, and reference them in the `Then` step:

```
Feature: MyFuture  

@Do something  
Scenario Outline: Verify bla bla    
    Given run I ... with <jj>,<kk>,<ll>  
    Then verify the following: <aa>, <bb>, <cc>

Examples:
    | jj | kk | ll | aa | bb | cc |
    | m  | n  | o  | d  | e  | f  |
    | p  | q  | r  | g  | h  | i  |
```